# How to make my maven project depend on non maven projects?

Tags: maven

I want to create a maven project, which has to depend on a non maven project which in turn depends on 2 other non maven projects. I do not have ownership of any of the other projects and it would not be possible for me to change anything in those projects let alone the structure to conform to the maven structure.

I asked if I could just get jars -- but was told that because of multiple levels of dependency, it would be "difficult" -- although I haven't understood why.

Is this possible or should I just abandon the use of maven to create my project and go with a regular project with jars in the lib folder?

Inxsible

Comment: possible duplicate of [what if my open source project is managaed by maven and depends on a library not in maven repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436069/what-if-my-open-source-project-is-managaed-by-maven-and-depends-on-a-library-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can go with a regular project build that means you *must* have access to the other project's jar files?

It doesn't really matter how the other project builds them, you can still gain more control over your own build process by loading the jars you depend on into a Maven repository.

I'd suggest using one of the following repository managers:

- [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/)
- [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php)
- [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)

They'll give you management screens to uploading 3rd party jars, they'll also a more efficient way to use other Maven repositories like [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).

Once you've got your Maven build process working, you could encourage the other projects to automatically publish their versions into your Maven repo. 
They could use the ANT tasks provided by the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) or [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) projects. Worst case you just continue to load their libraries until they see the light :-)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I guess I will have to be the one to show them the light.