# what if my open source project is managaed by maven and depends on a library not in maven repository?

Tags: maven

Imagine this case.  I have an open source project which I manage with Maven, and it depends on a well-known library (jpathwatch, e.g.) not in maven repository.  How can I make it work?

The straightforward way is to install jpathwatch to local maven repository.  However, that imposes a burden for people who check out my project's source code and want to build them by themselvz. They'll encounter an maven error and then look into the README file, or just give up trying.

Is there a clean way for me to work it around?  Do I have to go back to ANT ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make my maven project depend on non maven projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025614/how-to-make-my-maven-project-depend-on-non-maven-projects)

Comment: I find Maven a hobbled technology unless I'm also running a Maven repository manager like Nexus. Install it and you'll never look back

Comment: I am designing an open source project which I expect to be shared by people not in my company. While I can set up an Nexus in my company,  I can't presume that others would do the same thing.

Comment: Not the point. I could share code with you and still use my own Nexus instance. Maven repository managers are designed to "mirror" remote content so using it will automatically cache large repos like Maven Central (Increasing build speed and reliability). It also gives you much better visibility of how your projects are using jars (open source and otherwise). Without a repo manager you're not getting the full benefit of using Maven.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to do this is to upload the library to central (or failing that, if your project is not open source, to the maven repository that your project is hosted on).

There is the [guide on uploading 3rd party artifacts to central](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Uploading+3rd-party+Artifacts+to+The+Central+Repository) which details how to upload the artifact if the originating project doesn't want to.

There is also the possibility of just deploying the artifact under your own groupId... more of a last resort, or first resort if the official way seems too slow for you.

If you want to be a good open source citizen, upload that stuff to central, so that others will benefit.

Hacks like [in-project repositories](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/01/maven-in-project-repository.html) won't work for people who live behind a corporate repository manager and have `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` in their `~/.m2/settings.xml` (as they should have)

Hacks like `system` scope cause a never ending world of pain when people try to work with *your* project as a transitive dependencies... because guess what `${basedir}` evaluates to when resolving your project from the local repository and not from the reactor? try `~/.m2/repository/your-groupId/your-artifactId/your-version` which is definately *not* where you put that 3rd party jar file.

The `system` scope hack only works when you are building the final artifact, and even then it can have unintended side-effects (like the classpath that gets baked into the JAR manifest... it will be your machine's on-disk path... not the path that the user deploys to)

There are only three solutions:

1. Deploy it to a remote repo (preference goes to central)
2. Install it in local repo (with all the pain for end users)
3. The Fake module solution (wherein you fake out a JAR module and replace the “built” jar with the jar you want to sub-in so that the module is now the built artifact without building it... this will end up being option 1 or 2 but is a less evil solution than the "in project repository")

Comment: Thanks. Seems that I have to let people do local install.

Answer (score 1):

In such case you should bundle this library into your project and make use of `<system>` dependency scope, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/file.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Nooooooooooooo. `system` scope is evil. Use `mvn install:install-file` or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` instead

Comment: @StephenConnolly I don't think that `evil` is the right word :) Of course, it's better not to use it and have all dependencies in repositories, but I haven't come across any side-effects of its use (apart from the transitive dependency that you're mentioning).

Comment: And the malformed Manifest classpath is another critical side-effect... there are others but I'd need to dig them up. Fake module is as better solution than system scope

Comment: Agree the Stephen there are better more Maven-like alternatives to the system path

Comment: ${project.basedir} as a part of system path didn't work for me. Don't know why.  Also, system scope library would be not packaged when the project is assembled.

Comment: @KentChen it has to be `${basedir}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an in-project repository.

See [Leonid Dubinsky's Blog - Maven in-project repository](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/01/maven-in-project-repository.html)

Comment: Won't work for people who need `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` in their `~/.m2/settings.xml` (which *should* be everyone working in a corporate environment with a Maven Repository Manager)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a JAR file somewhere on the net and referencing it from the project is trivial. You can create your own Maven repository in three easy steps, please see my [post](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/3968).

Comment: Nooooooooooooo. `system` scope is evil. Use `mvn install:install-file` or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` instead